# display text inside a draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I would like to know how I can display text from a `textarea` into a draggable.

I have multiple text areas and draggables. My problem is when I try to upload a text from any text area, it is displayed in all the draggables.

How can i do this? I tried the `data` attribute and it still doesn't work. All I want is to display text inside a corresponding draggable. Please help.

```js
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'ui-widget-content',
        appendTo: '.container',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    });
});

$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function()
{
    $(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function()
{
    return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
    var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
    if (editingText.length)
    {
        editingText.hide();
        editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
    }
});

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).draggable();
    }
};

var vm = function() {
  var self=this;
  self.items=ko.observableArray();
  self.textContent1 = ko.observable('');
  self.textContent2 = ko.observable('');
  self.textContent3 = ko.observable('');
  self.init = function() {
    self.items([]);
  }
  self.remove = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    self.items.remove(item);
 }
 self.addNew = function() {
  var content = [ 
    self.textContent1(), 
    self.textContent2(), 
    self.textContent3()
  ].filter(function(item) {
    return item !== ''
  });
  content.forEach(function(item) { self.items.push(item); })
  self.textContent1('');
  self.textContent2('');
  self.textContent3('');
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<br/>
 <div class="item1">
  <textarea data-fid="hello" data-bind="value: textContent1" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="item2">
  <textarea data-fid="hello2" data-bind="value: textContent2" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="item3">
  <textarea  data-bind="value: textContent3" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: addNew">Generate New Div</button>

<div class="container">
  <div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
    <div href="#"  class="item1" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
      <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <center>
        <span class="text" data-fid="hello" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/>
      </center>
    </div><div href="#" class="item2" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
      <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <center>
        <span class="text"  data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you're describing. You _do_ include every draggable element twice though.. Remove one of the `<div>` element inside your `foreach: items`.

Comment: I need more draggables at least 4 and what I want is to enter text inside a draggables using text area let's say I want to use the 2nd text area I want the second draggables to display only the 2nd textera input I don't want to create multiple draggables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of unclear, but I believe you're asking how to create a number of draggable elements without having to deal with two `foreach` bindings: one for the inputs, one for the draggable elements.

You need to create one list of objects. Each object has an observable property that holds *its own* label.

*EDIT:* Trying to include the other requirements (as they're slowly becoming clear)...

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.draggable = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    $(element).draggable();
  }
};


var vm = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.draggableItems = ko.observableArray();
  self.addDraggable = function() {

    self.draggableItems.push({
      style: {
        padding: "1rem",
        position: "absolute",
        background: "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)"
      },
      label: ko.observable("Draggable nr. " + self.draggableItems().length)
    });

  };

}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: addDraggable">Add new draggable</button>

<div data-bind="foreach: draggableItems">

  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <textarea data-bind="value: label, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div data-bind="draggable: true, style: style">
    <div data-bind="text: label"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i am very sorry for wasting your time i am looking for something like this but at the same time im looking sor something that i can create a class so i can edit color font size the only way i can do this is by making it using class

Comment: all i want is to be able link my text area with a draggable that  is all

Comment: Please try to clearly describe your requirements and what you've tried.. You're contradicting your own question and comments in every new sentence.

Comment: what i want is i have 2 draggables and 2 textareas (dont pay attension to the third textarea) i want text area 1 to insert text to draggable 1 only and text area2 to draggable 2 only. i dont want to write on text area 1 and display on draggable 1 and 2

Comment: I've sligthly modified my answer to hopefully answer your question a bit better. In this example there's a button add items; if you just need 2 you can initialize the `draggableItems` array with two objects.

Comment: yes that is what i was looking for but their is still the problem with class="item" i need class so i can edit each draggale text like change color font and text but thank you